# Need VBA That Works With and Without OneDrive

Tags: vba, path, onedrive

I have code that opens a .txt file saved off of the desktop.  It works great unless the user has OneDrive, then I receive an error.  Is there a way to make the code dynamic to recognise if it is a OneDrive environment or not?

```
Sub OPENER()


'
' new_open Macro
'

'
    user = Environ("Username")
    ChDir "C:\Users\" & user & "\Desktop"
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\" & user & "\Desktop\next.txt", Origin:=437 _
        , StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
        Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array( _
        3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Test if the normal desktop path exist (or in fact, if the file `next.txt` first, if yes then use path without OneDrive else test if the path with OneDrive works. You should always test if the file exist first before trying to do anything with it (in your case, open)

Comment: You can get the desktop path like this: `Createobject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\"`